How to run a sagemaker pipeline with multiple data inputs in the preprocessing script?
I am trying to run a sagemaker pipeline with multiple data inputs in my data preprocessing script. When I run the pipeline with just one data input it runs, but when I introduce a second data input which I need to merge in the preprocessing step, I have receive two different kind of errors:

'FailureReason': 'ClientError: AlgorithmError: , exit code: 1',
'FailureReason': 'ClientError: Failed to invoke sagemaker:CreateProcessingJob. Error Details: null',

Note: I have been able to successfully run the pipeline with each data input individually, so I know the pipeline is able to the read the data in. There's something about the way I am introducing the multiple paramters/data inputs that is not working.
This is what my parameters look like:
`from sagemaker.workflow.parameters import (
ParameterInteger,
ParameterString,)
Processing_instance_count =      
ParameterInteger(name="ProcessingInstanceCount",default_value=1)

data_input1 = ParameterString(name="data1",default_value=data1,)
data_input2 = ParameterString(name="data2",default_value=data2,)`

My processing step:
process_step = ProcessingStep(     
    name="...",     
    processor=sklearn_processor,     
    inputs=[         
        ProcessingInput(source=data1, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),        
        ProcessingInput(source=data2, destination="/opt/ml/processing/input"),],     
    outputs=[         
        ProcessingOutput(output_name="...", source="/opt/ml/processing/output"),],    code=preprocess_script_uri,     
)

And then the pipeline definition:
pipeline_name = f"..."      
    pipeline = Pipeline(     
        name=pipeline_name,     
        parameters=[         
            processing_instance_count,         
            data_input1,         
            data_input2,     ],     
        steps=[process_step],     
)


In your code where constructing ProcessingStep, you are specifying two ProcessingInputs and they have same destination path ("/opt/ml/processing/input"). Seeing the ml-ops sample notebooks in the amazon-sagemaker-examples repo, they use different destination paths when using multiple ProcessingInputs. Please try specifying different paths and check if the issue resolves.
